# Why the array pointer not pointing to the beginning of the array after copy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I try to pass psamples2 array pointer to function but it keeps passing garbage ( end array ? )
also why cpointer keep the iteration value and not the beginning of the array ?
my question is why psamples2 is not pointing to the beginning of the array .

```
#   define kiss_fft_scalar float
float samples[2048]  = {0};
float* psamples = samples;
float* psamples2 =  samples;
int offset = 0;
while (!_exitThread) { // some where in the code its false

     short* target = psamples + offset;;
     if(offset<2048)
     {
        float *src = offset; //just  numbers 
        *target = *src;
         // Now the psamples and the psamples2 pointers are updated with pointing to the element  
           //in the array and not to the beginning why ?

     }
     _exitThread = true;
 }

 kiss_fftr( (kiss_fft_scalar*)psamples );


// ---------------------- This is function in some module in the app here is just the signature -----

// this is the C function that getting the kiss_fft_scalar *timedata that revived as garbage
void kiss_fftr( const kiss_fft_scalar *timedata )
{
  // the result of *timedata is 8.52120011e-038 as i understand is should be the pointer to the array 
}
```

Comment: How about just "float* psamples2 = &samples;"?

Comment: Side note: If I'm not mistaken, with your current score, you should know a little better how to write down a question properly. I did not down-vote you (I never down-vote anyone), but there's a dissonance between your score on SO and the (improper) format of this question.

Comment: `short* target = psamples + offset;` - that *doesn't* flag a big fat warning at compilation?

Comment: are you sure that samples is not overflowing in the stack?

Comment: @pmverma im getting :
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'short (*)[2048]' to 'short *'

Comment: voting to close. with your reputation you should be come up with a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem. currently it's just a huge mess.

Comment: ok i fixed the code hope its better

Comment: Change `float *psamples = samples` to `float *psamples = samples[0]`, and also do the same for `psamples2`

Comment: I looked at ten of your questions, and none of them were pretty in the first revision. You owe your reputation to those who edit your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the body of your loop

```
while(!_exitThread)
```

sets `_exitThread` so would a plain `if()` statement suffice?

Secondly, you are switching pointer types from `float*` to `short*` and confusing the situation by adding `offset` and it's unclear whether the compiler will add `offset * sizeof(float)` or `offset * sizeof(short)`.

```
short* target = psamples + offset;;
```

Thirdly you haven't shown where you are using `psamples2` although you are complaining about it. Fourth you haven't initialised `src` before you set the `float` it points to with an `int` value;

```
float *src = offset;
```

You are assigning an `int` to a pointer. Why don't you turn on your compiler warnings?

Comment: Note that it's not unclear what the compiler does, `psamples + offset` increments the `psamples` pointer by `offset` items, since `psamples` is a `float*`, that's `offset * sizeof(float)` bytes. Why the code assign it to a short* is highly suspicious though.